# count 0.5 for some IDs

Tags: ms-access

So this is for my dissertation and it is coming allong pretty well. almost finished it now xD

Anyway, I'm making a pub Epos system in access and its all OK, except now I have reached the stock control.

To get the query (Stock = Stock - Sales) I need to do a count query, which is easy enough, though the problem with pubs is they often serve half pints...

Is there any way to get the count SQL function to count certain ProductID's as 0.5?

This is a part of the table, and Product ID 2,4,6,8 and 10 are all relating to half pints and so count needs to recognise them as 0.5 instead of 1.

[URL=http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/688/2121212e.png/][IMG]http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/64/2121212e.png[/IMG][/URL]

Thanks

Sam

Comment: How would I use a case statement? so far I have 

SELECT TblTotalSale.ProductID, Count(TblTotalSale.TotalSalesID) AS CountOfTotalSalesID, TblProduct.Item
FROM TblProduct INNER JOIN TblTotalSale ON TblProduct.ProductID = TblTotalSale.ProductID
GROUP BY TblTotalSale.ProductID, TblProduct.Item;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you need to separate products purchased from products sold, lets say you called products sold "servings".

product (productId, supplierId, orderQuantity, reorderTrigger)

serving (servingId, productId, servingDesc, volumeOfServe)

this way you can have two servings of the one product (eq guiness)

servingDesc - "Guiness 1/2 pint" volumeOfServe - 0.5

servingDesc - "Guiness pint" volumeOfServe - 1

Comment: This is what I did, kinda. got it working in the end.

I had to completely re design all of my tables but have sizes small and large for each of the draught drinks and a selection.

I found that sum did not like 0.5, so I set delivery as half pints, i.e "1" as a half pint and "2" as a pint.

Thank you ChrisPadgham and @HansUp both